# Who fires the DOMContentLoaded event?

Tags: html, angularjs, windows, events, browser

AngularJS begins to bootstrap the application when the DOMContentLoaded is fired. But who fires the DOMContentLoaded event? Is it the browser (Mozilla, IE, Chrome etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the browser. Even though the events are pretty standardized now, particular events used to work for some browsers and not others, and some newer events / global variables are being added to the newer versions of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event - load
>   - should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be
>   much more appropriate, so be cautious.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Yes, from what I read here, it is fired by the browser.